# Simple Magento question

Tags: php, magento

I have a website in Magento, it's still very simple and unfinished.

Since I'm a beginner in this field, I'd like someone to point me to a solution:
How do I change the Checkout link text?
Is it done inside the phtml/XML structure or inside admin panel?
this is my website: [notice the Checkout link]
http://gale.dev4.webenabled.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to change the text in the the following template

\app\design\frontend\enterprise\default\template\checkout\cart\cartheader.phtml

Kindly note that this is a directory path from an enterprise installation. Yours might be different but the filename of the template should be the same.

Another option is to use the locale files to actually change by Specifying a translation in the appropriate locale file.

HTH :)

Answer (score 2):

you can find locale files under app/locale/language_CODE and change the translation from there . To find the translations either use file search or grep for the string you are looking for

```
grep '"Checkout"' app/locale/en_US/ -rsn
```

this will show you filename, line number and the searched string:

```
app/locale/en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv:40:"Checkout","Checkout"
```

remember that locale files are utf-8 encoded and cache must be cleared after changing localizations